# A Surprising Riley Riddle

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, affix-riddle

> My infix is a potato reporter,
>
> My suffix is a garden storer,
>
> My prefix is Martin's significant other,
>
> My whole will make you bowled over.

What am I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is:

> **ASTONISHED**

*My infix is a potato reporter,*

> This clues [**NISH** Kumar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nish_Kumar) - a British stand-up comedian who hosts the BBC Two show *The Mash Report*. With the connection between ['mash' and '*potato*'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mashed_potato), Nish could be considered a '*potato reporter*'.
>
>  <sup>**Original attempt, superseded:** **I** sounds like 'EYE', a growing point on the skin of a *potato*. '*Reporter*' here is intended as a 'sounds like' indicator like in a cryptic crossword clue...</sup>

*My suffix is a garden storer,*

> A **SHED** is a building used for *storage* found in a *garden*.

*My prefix is Martin's significant other,*

> [**ASTON** Martin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aston_Martin) is a British car manufacturer, famously favoured by the fictional secret agent James Bond.

*My whole will make you bowled over.*

> ASTON + NISH + SHED = **ASTONISHED** is a synonym for '*bowled over*' or 'surprised' (as in the title).

Comment: Your answer is very close to being correct but one of your -fixes are wrong...

Comment: @aguy Any better now? :)

Comment: There you go! I thought the prefix clue was quite difficult, but it surely didn't stop you!